# How do I copy the cuda input array into the shared array?

Tags: cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I'm trying to copy a CUDA input array into a shared memory array. The first `n` values copy into the shared array perfectly but after that there are some pretty weird patterns happening. Can anyone find what I'm doing wrong/what's happening here?

I've tried using `s_x[tid] = x[tid]`, `s_x[row]= x[row]`, and the other two combinations as well. I know they wouldn't logically make sense but gotta try everything.

Here is the kernel function I wrote:

```
__global__ void mv_cuda_shared(float* y, float* A, float* x, int n)
{
    extern __shared__ float s_x[];
    int row = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int tid = threadIdx.x;
    s_x[row] = x[row];
    __syncthreads();
    if(tid == 0 && row == 0)
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            printf("s_x[%d] = %10.6f x = %10.6f\n", i, s_x[i], x[i]);
        }
    float temp = 0;
    if(row < n)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        {
            temp += (A[row*n + k] * s_x[k]);
        }
    }
    y[row] = temp;
}
```

and here is where I call it in the `main` method (omitting all the `cudaMallocs` and copying):

```
mv_cuda_shared<<<(N/BLOCK_SIZE), BLOCK_SIZE, N*sizeof(float)>>>(d_y, d_A, d_x, N);
```

So I expect `s_x` to match `x`. But, instead the first `N` elements (`N` is the same as `n`) are copied correctly but then the rest seem to follow a pattern. For example the four entries after `s_x[N-1]` are say, 1. Then the four after that are like, 0.24566... (I checked and the number isn't even in the original array). So anyhow, can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Comment: `s_x[row]` is definitely wrong.  `N*sizeof(float)` is also wrong, it should be `BLOCK_SIZE*sizeof(float)`.  You're only launching `N` threads in total.  Why would you expect more than `N` values to be copied (e.g. why would you expect values after `s_x[N-1]` to have any value)?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing in this code makes much sense, but if the intention is really to load `n` elements of the global memory array into shared memory for every block, the copy code would have to look something like:

```
    extern __shared__ float s_x[];
    int tid = threadIdx.x;
    for(int i=tid; i<n; i+=blockDim.x) {
       s_x[i] = x[i];
    }
    __syncthreads();
```

However, I doubt that is really what you require, and suspect you might be harbouring the (incorrect) notion that `s_x` is shared across all blocks, rather than at block scope, meaning that each block would have its own complete copy of that array in shared memory.